# Erro 503 "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Tags: ajax, datasnap

estou tentando fazer uma conexão no datasnap usando ajax

meu codigo:

```
                var url = 'http://cloud.nooven.com.br:12345/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/CriaSessao/'+cpfCnpj+'|'+usuario+'|'+senha;
                console.log(url);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('sucesso');
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        console.log('erro');
                    }
                });
```

a pagina `.html` que to acessando ta no servidor, por isso esta como localhost na variavel `url`, o erro que ocorre é esse:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cloud.nooven.com.br:12345/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/CriaSessao/68243096000152%7CMOACIR%7C123456. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cloud.nooven.com.br' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

obrigado.

Comment: aonde eu to usando @GuilhermeNascimento ???

Comment: ah, apenas usei, nada demais, eu troquei o 'jsonp' por 'json' e mudou o erro: ' XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cloud.nooven.com.br:12345/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/CriaSessao/68243096000152%7CMOACIR%7C123456. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cloud.nooven.com.br' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503. '

Comment: em php, eu resolvia com o header( "Allow - ......

Comment: sim, uma hospedagem minha

Comment: o codigo está em delphi, é um datasnap

Comment: Costumo resolver assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92269/qual-%C3%A9-o-nome-da-opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quando-fazemos-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-para-o-servidor-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme este link [CORS on DataSnap REST Server](http://delphi.org/2015/04/cors-on-datasnap-rest-server/) você deve usar assim:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  //Permite requisições de diferentes dominios
  Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
    FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

Comment: coloquei no delphi, mas continua com o mesmo erro :(  'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cloud.nooven.com.br:3715/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/CriaSessao/68243096000152%7CMOACIR%7C123456. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cloud.nooven.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.'

Comment: @Furlan não tenho conhecimento com tal tecnologia, mas vou suport duas coisas. Ou você não reiniciou o aplicativo ou você colocou o código aleatoriamente em qualquer lugar. Como eu não tenho o seu código original, não faço ideia da onde indicar o local para adicionar o método. Se puder adicionar detalhes a pergunta