# Qual é o nome da operação quando fazemos uma requisição ajax para o servidor interno que por sua vez pega informação de externo?

Tags: servidor, requisição

Eu sempre faço isso, mas não sei qual é o nome técnico disso.

Quando preciso fazer alguma requisição, onde pego uma informação de um conteúdo externo (por exemplo o facebook), sempre uso o meu servidor (através do PHP) e capturo essa requisição, para só depois capturar isso via ajax.

Ficando assim:

[image: Imagem explicando o problema.]

Conversando com algums amigos aqui do SOPT, me disseram que se chama **Proxying**, mas ainda assim fiquei com dúvidas (tudo que achei na internet estava em inglês.

O nome desse tipo de procedimento é realmente *Proxying*?

Existe algum outro tipo de nome para esse tipo de operação?

Comment: Se alguém puder ajudar corrigindo as tags, pois até nisso estou perdido.

Comment: Talvez     cross-domain?

Comment: Cross-domain se refere à aplicações web que se comunicam fora do seu domínio/servidor web. Isso pode ser na forma de requisições de rede para outros servidores ou compartilhamento de dados com componentes DOM servidos de diferentes domínios compostos na mesma página web.

Comment: Acho que eu tinha que ter colocado as setinhas! **AJAX -> INTERNO -> EXTERNO**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Proxy** em inglês significa procurador, representante.

No contexto da computação, é qualquer servidor que aja como intermediário para clientes pedindo recursos de outros servidores – e aí você percebe por que a analogia do *procurador* faz sentido:

- Quando você nomeia alguém como seu procurador, ele passa a ter autorização para fazer coisas que sejam do seu interesse. Segundo o dicionário Houaiss, trata-se d'*aquele que exerce um papel **intermediário** entre as partes interessadas*.
- Quando você usa um servidor proxy, ele faz pedidos que são do seu interesse para depois te retornar, exercendo um papel **intermediário** entre o cliente e o servidor do recurso final, assim como o procurador.

O ato de utilizar procedimentos com um servidor proxy é chamado de proxying. A operação que você faz é usual e da forma mais ortodoxa possível, sem nada que descaracterize o conceito, portanto não vejo sentido em chamar isso de qualquer outra coisa além de proxying.

Comment: Gosto de usar isso para driblar o _Access-Control-Allow-Origin_

Answer (score 9):

> **O nome desse tipo de procedimento é realmente Proxying?**

**Sim**, é. Do [artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy),

> um proxy (em português *procurador*) é um servidor que age como um intermediário para requisições de clientes solicitando recursos de outros servidores.

É uma solução bastante utilizada atualmente para evitar [conflitos com especificações CORS](http://blog.javascripting.com/2015/01/17/dont-hassle-with-cors/).

> **Existe algum outro tipo de nome para esse tipo de operação?**

Existem vários. Por se tratar de uma funcionalidade incorporada a um serviço web, o servidor intermediário [também pode ser chamado de *broker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture#Web_services_approach), e a operação em si, *brokerage*.

Se o serviço simplesmente repassa chamadas HTTP, encapsulando chamadas no formato esperado pelo servidor destino, pode também [ser chamado de *tuneller*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel).

Comment: Broker eu traduziria como "corretor" (é isso mesmo?)

Comment: @bfavaretto esse é o sentido comercial - neste caso, acho que 'agente' , por ser um termo importado de arquitetura de processos, funciona um pouco melhor. Ou talvez 'intermediário'.

Comment: A técnica de HTTP tunneling não está relacionada à situação descrita pelo AP. Ela é usada para contornar as limitações de um ambiente com acesso restrito a rede ou para acessar uma rede com acesso restrito. Na situação descrita, não faz sentido encaminhar pedidos de maneira "cega", pois isso seria um desperdício de recursos e/ou abriria uma brecha de segurança.

Comment: @rodorgas Isso não é exatamente verdade. O que você descreve é um tipo de implementação de socket proxy onde vários protocolos podem ser encapsulados em uma chamada HTTP, geralmente sob encriptação, que é capaz de trafegar entre segmentos de rede com limitações impostas sobre os protocolos originais. Ainda assim, uma implementação de serviço que faça simplesmente o mapeamento de URIs locais (http://localhost/servidorremoto/url.ext) para URIs de um serviço remoto (http://servidorremoto/url.ext) também é chamado de tunelamento.

Comment: @rodorgas referência - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171412/rest-api-rule-about-tunneling

Comment: :p tem razão! +1