# Servidor HTTPS consulta cep dos correios

Tags: javascript, json, http, web-service, https

Estou tentando requisitar o endereço pelo cep em um site, porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://meusite.com.br' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/20040901.json'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

O servidor que meu site está hospedado é HTTPS então acredito que seja esse o problema... alguém conhece um site para consulta que também seja HTTPS para não dar erro de segurança?

Comment: Não é só você colocar `//:url` ao invés de `http://url`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters fiz isso e deu o seguinte erro: `GET https://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/20040901.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: É erro no servidor do correio então.

Comment: Deixa eu perguntar, você usa alguma linguagem de servidor (server-side)? Eu tenho uma solução para isso que acabou com essas dores de cabeça

Comment: Quando você usa o protocolo HTTPS quando quer transitar dados eles  devem ser via protocolo HTTPS, no seu caso o seu servidor está usando o protocolo HTTPS mas o webservice do correios não, então ele não permite você fazer requisição pra um protocolo inseguro (no caso o http), faça o teste: faça a requisição através do procolo http, provavelmente irá funcionar.

Comment: @Laerte sim, isso mesmo... o problema que não posso fazer isso porque o sistema precisa estar em um servidor https

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, uso php framework Laravel

Comment: Cara eu dei uma olhada aqui, a única solução é ter essa URL disponível via https ou você trabalhar com HTTP, mas como você mesmo disse não será possível.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você usa o protocolo HTTPS e precisa realizar requisições elas devem ser via HTTPS. Por questões de segurança.

No seu caso o seu servidor está usando o HTTPS mas o Web Service do Correios não, então ele não permite você fazer requisição pro servidor dos Correios por considera inseguro.

Mas você pode fazer requisições pro protocolo HTTPS via HTTP, *exemplo: CDN.*

A maioria dos browsers atuais **bloqueia esse tipo de requisição**, chamada de **Mixed Content**.

> **Para domínios de terceiros**, use a versão HTTPS do site, **se disponível**. Se HTTPS não estiver disponível, você pode tentar entrar
>   em contato com o domínio e perguntar se eles podem tornar o conteúdo
>   disponível via HTTPS.

**Fontes:**
[What is Mixed Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251129/5314295)
[How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Answer (score 0):

Silvão, na boa? Já que você está usando `Laravel`, que tal usar um **Proxinig**?

Vai funcionar da seguinte forma: Você pega envia uma requisição para a url do cep pelo `Laravel`, e pelo `jQuery`, você enviar a requisição para o `Laravel`.

Te evitará muitas dores de cabeça, já que estará fazendo a requisição para o seu próprio domínio:

```
Route::get('cep/{cep}', function ($cep)
{
     $url = sprintf('http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/%s.json', $cep);

     $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

     return Response::json($json);
});
```

No seu jQuery, faça apenas isso:

```
$.get('/cep/' + cep, {}, function (response) { /** ... **/ });
```

A vantagem desse tipo de requisição é que você não precisa se preocupar com essas <del>chatisses</del> limitações impostas pelos navegadores.

Entenda mais sobre o assunto em:

[Qual é o nome da operação quando fazemos uma requisição ajax para o servidor interno que por sua vez pega informação de externo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92269/qual-%C3%A9-o-nome-da-opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quando-fazemos-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-para-o-servidor-int/93802#93802)